# Assign multiple key/value pairs at once

Tags: perl

Is it possible to do this assignment as some type of array assignment instead so it's not so verbose?

```perl
    $byRobotNumber->{'inquiry'} = $tokens->[13];
    $byRobotNumber->{'rch'} = $tokens->[16];
    $byRobotNumber->{'serial'} = $tokens->[3];
```

$byRobotNumber is obviously a reference to a hash here, and $tokens is a reference to an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use hash slices, in our case hashref slices.

The first trick is hash slices: if `%h` is a hash, `@h{LIST}` is a hash slice, returning the list of values corresponding to the LIST of keys. It can be an lvalue too.

The second trick is that when you have a hashref `$hr`, `{$hr}` behaves the same way as the sigil-less core `h` of hash `%h`.

The same thing works with arrays as well. Which leads us to this:

```
@{$byRobotNumber}{qw(inquiry rch serial)} = @{$tokens}[13,16,3];
```

Comment: And if the number of items becomes unwieldy, you can create another hash for mapping keys to indexes, e.g. `my %mapping = (foo => 1, bar => 12); @{$byRobotNumber}{keys %mapping} = @{$tokens}[values %mapping];`

Answer (score 5):

You can assign values to variables in parallel by using lists on each side of the equals sign:

```
( $byRobotNumber->{'inquiry'}, 
  $byRobotNumber->{'rch'}, 
  $byRobotNumber->{'serial'}
) = ($tokens->[13], $tokens->[16], $tokens->[3]);
```

OR the simpler option is to use a hash slice and an array slice:

```
@{$byRobotNumber}{qw/inquiry rch serial/} = @{$tokens}[qw/13 16 3/]
```